# Scrolling to a certain element after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to scroll to a certain element on the page after an ajax call, but it's not working for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

**test.php**

```
<style>
#divOne {
border: 1px solid red;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
#divTwo {
border: 1px solid blue;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
</style>

<input id = 'click' type = 'submit' value = 'Click' onclick = "ajaxCall('testx.php')">
<div id = 'divOne'></div>
<div id = 'divTwo'></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function ajaxCall(action) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
        success:function(data) {
            document.getElementById('divTwo').innerHTML = data;        
        }, //end of success:function(data)
        complete:function(data) {
            $("#click").click(function (){
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#divTwo").offset().top
                }, 2000);   
        } //end of complete:function(data)
    }); //end of $.ajax({

} //end of function ajaxCall()

</script>
```

**testx.php**

```
<?php

echo "Hello World!";

?>
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Hello World! 
(The page to scroll to #divTwo)
```

**Actual Result:**

```
Hello World! 
(The page DID NOT scroll to #divTwo)
```

Comment: @barmar I need to execute this AFTER an ajax call.

Comment: Why do you think the code in that question won't work after an AJAX call?

Comment: @barmar Ok. I will re-ask this question, after I try to use the code in the question, and it doesn't work again.

Comment: Just give your elements some actual height. Instead of height:100% use height:400px for example.

Comment: @jessica Don't reask. If it doesn't work, update the question and request that it be reopened.

Comment: @Barmar Edited it. Doesn't work, like I expected.

Comment: @Barmar That answer is for BEFORE ajax call, I need answer for AFTER ajax call.

Comment: That answer doesn't have anything to do with AJAX at all. It's just how to scroll to an element correctly. You can use it before or after an AJAX call and it will work the same.

Comment: @Barmar Should I re-ask this question then? Since, I edited it, and it doesn't work ,and you're still telling me that it's working?

Comment: You need to put the code into the `complete:` function, in place of `document.location.hash = "divTwo"`

Comment: @barmar Did it, edited it, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You're not scrolling, you're just defining a handler that scrolls when you click on another element. Do you read the code that you're copying, and try to understand the parts of it?

Comment: @Barmar I DON'T understand it. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: You use jQuery and you don't understand what `$("#click").click()` does? That's one of the most basic features.

Comment: @Barmar Now, I know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your complete function is just defining a click handler, not actually performing the scroll. Just put the code that does the scroll, without putting it inside `.click()`.

```
    complete:function(data) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#divTwo").offset().top
        }, 2000);   
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for this.  Works beautifully!